# Cancancan in a engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, cancancan

I want to use the rails gem cancancan in an engine (https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan). So I added it to my gemspec file like this:

```
s.add_dependency "cancancan"
```

In the engines dummy app and in a test app I load my engine and I'm getting always errors about undefined methods for every cancancan method.

```
undefined local variable or method `load_and_authorize_resource'
undefined local variable or method `can?'
[...]
```

This is my `ability.rb` file in the main app:

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    user ||= User.new # guest user (not logged in)
    can :manage, :all
  end
end
```

I tried several solutions for using cancancan in engines but I found no solution for my engine. Here are some examples:

- http://mx.kelsin.net/2011/08/10/using-cancan-in-a-engine-and-your-app/
- https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan/wiki/Authorization-for-Namespaced-Controllers
- https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan/wiki/Admin-Namespace

Where is my fault? Is one of the posted links really the solution or are they wrong/outdated? Is there a good tutorial to use cancancan in an engine? Thanks!

Comment: did you try `authorize_resource class: false` in the controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could solve my problem by updating Cancancan from 1.9.2 to actual 1.10.1 and compare my engine with the one from this post: https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan/issues/151#issuecomment-69487040

Answer (score 0):

you have `load_and_authorize_resource` in your `WelcomeController`, it's trying to load the `Welcome` model which doesn't exist. Instead, trying using `authorize_resource class: false`, so

```
 class WelcomeController < ApplicationController
   authorize_resource class: false
   # rest of your code
 end
```

Comment: I get also the error `undefined method 'authorize_resource' for HomeController:Class`. That's my problem: no method of Cancancan works in the dummy app of the engine. Any other suggestions?